# Looking for a note taking site with a public API

Tags: note-taking

I have a service running on a Raspberry Pi at home during the day that records data, and I'd like to make the daily results available to read while I'm out, so I'm looking for recommendations for a note taking site with a public API that I can create an empty document each day, write the results to over the course of the day, and read either via an app or web browser.

Comment: Why not cut out the middleman and access whatever's on your Raspberry Pi with a web browser? You could use a lightweight web server such as Nginx or lighttpd.

Comment: I had a similar setup to that before, and my pi ended up getting hacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by signing up for the google docs API 
It's not ideal, but it works well enough that I can use it

Answer (score 0):

You may also just use a plaintext note format (e.g. [org-mode](https://orgmode.org/)) and upload them directly to a storage service such as Dropbox?

Comment: that might be an option, create a new file each day, and synchronise it with Dropbox/Google Drive/OneDrive/etc